# Gatsby + tsc doesn't transpile rest operator

Tags: typescript, gatsby

I'm trying to get Gatsby to use TypeScript, by following the instructions [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-typescript/), but for some reason, `tsc` doesn't transpile the rest (`...`) operator, instead throwing the following error:

```
 WAIT  Compiling...

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors

 error  in ./src/components/Input.tsx

Syntax Error: Unexpected token (26:95)

> 26 | const Input = ({ text, ...inputProps }) => (react_1.default.createElement(
     |                        ^
```

If I run `tsc` from the command line, the file is transpiled correctly, replacing `...` with a call to `__rest`.

Here's my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/"
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

As you can see, it's very minimal. I've tried using a bunch of `lib`s (from the [Compiler Options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)) and other options, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `"target": "es5"` to your `tsconfig.json` because [Gatsby defaults to `"target": "esnext"`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-typescript/).

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

It will instruct TypeScript to transpile the ES6 code to ES5.

The `lib` option you tried only changes the way TypeScript will type-check your code. For example when using `"target": "es5"` TypeScript will disallow the use of `Promise` because it is not part of the ES5 standard.

By adding `"lib": ["dom", "es6"]` you tell him to compile to ES5 will using the ES6 standard library + the DOM APIs (which are not part of ECMAScript, like `document`).

Update, using Gatsby configuration :

```
plugins: [
  {
    resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-typescript',
    options: {
      transpileOnly: true, // default
      compilerOptions: {
        target: 'es5',
        experimentalDecorators: true,
        jsx: `react`
      }, // default
    }
  },
]
```

Comment: I've tried using all valid targets - "ES3", "ES5", "ES6", "ES2015", "ES2016", "ES2017" and "ESNext" - all with the same result. :(

Comment: I added a code-block using the Gatsby configuration file, can you try it? Gatbsy is maybe ignoring your `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: Wow, that seems to work! I knew I was right to distrust Gatsby! Thank you!